# too many values to unpack (expected 11)

Tags: python, csv, python-3.x

I have a program that reads from a text file that contains how many people use emails that the user enter.This is my code:

```
user = input('Enter an email: ')
f_in = open('us-500.csv','rt')
c = 0
f_in.readline()
for line in f_in:
    line = line.strip(' ')
    first, last, company, address, city, country, state, phone1, phone2, email, web = line.split(',')
    for count in line:
        if count == user:
            c +=1
print(c)

f_in.close()
```

Comment: Can you describe the error ?

Comment: I couldn't read the file because it says too many values to unpack. I just I wanna count how many emails in the file

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there are less columns in the csv file then you expect to see. Debug the code and see what the `line` value is before splitting it by comma.

Also, I would use [`csv` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) instead:

```
import csv

user = input('Enter an email: ')
with open('us-500.csv', 'r') as f_in:
    reader = csv.reader(f_in)

    row = next(reader)
    print(row)  # see if row has 11 items
    first, last, company, address, city, country, state, phone1, phone2, email, web = row
```

Comment: the code works but it does it print the emails in the file. I think I missed something

Answer (score 0):

```
first, last, company, address, city, country, state, phone1, phone2, email, web = line.split(',')
```

You have 11 variables on the left hand side. This means that in order for the assignment to be successful, there have to be exactly 11 parts on the right hand side. So in your case, `line.split(',')` needs to yield exactly 11 items.

From the error message, this does not seem to be the case: There are more than 11 values. So you should check the content of the file to figure out what more values there are. Maybe you forgot a variable or two.

Alternatively, you could also change the assignment so you can take any number of *more* items. To do that, add a `*rest` name at the end. The star makes sure that any remaining items are stored in that variable as a list:

```
>>> a, b, *c = 'a,b,c,d,e,f'.split(',')
>>> c
['c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
```

Comment: the code works but it does it print the emails in the file. I think I missed something